# Django controller to require method

Tags: python, django

I read the following page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/decorators/

Basically, I have a function in a controller that only accepts POST requests. And the documentation on that page allowed me to do that. However, i'm noticing that when the user sends a GET or PUT etc, the response is literally nothing. How can I send a generic error or a 404 page or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't return nothing. It returns a 405 Method Not Allowed HTTP status code. This indicates to the client that the requested method is not allowed (as the name describes).

If you're dead set on returning something else, just don't use the decorator. All it does is test if the requested method is in the allowed list of methods. Just add the following to your view code and you can do whatever you want for each condition:

```
if request.method in ['GET', 'POST']:
    // allowed
else:
    // not allowed
```

Comment: Yeah...was thinking of doing it that way. But wasn't sure if there was a generic way using the decorator above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember if it was `request.method` or not and I don't have Django currently installed on any machines to double-check, but something like this could work.

```
@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # return a 404 or something
    # or
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # return a 404 or something
```

But shouldn't you be getting your generic `405 - Method not allowed` return page if you've only allowed `POST` for eg. to a certain controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this =) Good luck!

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed

def my_view(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=('POST',))
```

Comment: That's what the decorator *already* does, so not really a solution.

Comment: Well, actually is the same solution as the decorator.